# Cannot update Windows 10 due to Symantec Endpoint protection

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, anti-virus

I am trying to update Windows 10 "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607." The update failed due to the error "These programs need to be uninstalled because they aren't compatible with the upgrade - Symantec Endpoint Protection".

I would like to update Windows 10 without uninstalling Symantec. How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is, because a) you haven't actually asked one, and b) you've answered it anyway. Symantec Endpoint Protection is the culprit; either update or remove it, and try the 1607 Win10 update again.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. I have added more information.

Comment: Since we cannot recommend software (even though I so desperately want to, Symantec is pretty awful imo) the first step would be to try and update Symantec Endpoint Protection.

Comment: You either need to install a version of SEP that specifically supports Version 1607 or uninstall it and update your system, then install it again after the fact.  The incompatability is likely a soft incompatability, in that, Microsoft has determined it can or has cause a problem for users.  This check is done for your own good, so you don't have to contact us with a bigger problem, like your system is stuck in a boot loop because of SEP.  Saying you need to update or uninstall SEP, is a given, so I won't be submitting an answer.